# Why does my insert command insert duplicate rows for each insert?

Tags: vb.net, insert

This was working correctly, but now its inserting duplicate rows everytime I perform an insert from the page.  Both rows are good with all data inserted correctly, but its putting the record in the database twice each time.  How do I stop this?

VB.net code:

```
Protected Sub gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) Handles gvOnCallSchedule.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Insert" AndAlso Page.IsValid Then
        Try
           dsOncallGroup.Insert()
        Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
        End Try
    End If


    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
        Try
            dsOncallGroup.Delete()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
        End Try

        'Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End If


End Sub


Protected Sub dsOnCallGroup_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles dsOncallGroup.Inserting
    Dim strddlGroupName As New DropDownList
    Dim txtStartOnCall As New TextBox
    Dim txtEndOnCall As New TextBox
    Dim txtRank As New TextBox
    Dim strddlEmpName As New DropDownList
    Dim strddlOCPreferredContact As New DropDownList
    Dim txtEmpWorkPhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpHomePhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpHomeCellPhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpAltPhone As New TextBox


    strddlGroupName = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("ftrddlOCGroup"), DropDownList)
    txtStartOnCall = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStartOnCallFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEndOnCall = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndOnCallFtr"), TextBox)
    txtRank = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCallOrderFtr"), TextBox)
    strddlEmpName = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlAnalystFtr"), DropDownList)
    strddlOCPreferredContact = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("ftrddlOCPreferredContact"), DropDownList)
    txtEmpWorkPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtWorkPhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpHomePhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHomePhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpHomeCellPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHomeCellPhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpAltPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAltPhoneFtr"), TextBox)


    e.Command.Parameters("@fldOnCallGroup").Value = strddlGroupName.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldStartOnCall").Value = txtStartOnCall.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEndOnCall").Value = txtEndOnCall.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldRank").Value = txtRank.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpName").Value = strddlEmpName.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldOCPreferredContact").Value = strddlOCPreferredContact.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpWorkPhone").Value = txtEmpWorkPhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpHomePhone").Value = txtEmpHomePhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpHomeCellPhone").Value = txtEmpHomeCellPhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpAltPhone").Value = txtEmpAltPhone.Text

  End Sub
```

ASP code
Datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsOncallGroup" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscussSQLConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblOnCallSchedule WHERE (tblOnCallSchedule.fldOnCallGroup = @fldOnCallGroup) 
                   AND (tblOnCallSchedule.fldEndOnCall &gt; GETDATE()) 
                   ORDER BY tblOnCallSchedule.fldOnCallGroup, tblOnCallSchedule.fldEndOnCall, tblOnCallSchedule.fldRank" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tblOnCallSchedule WHERE fldOCID = @original_fldOCID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblOnCallSchedule] ([fldOnCallGroup], [fldStartOnCall], [fldEndOnCall], [fldRank], [fldEmpName], [fldOCPreferredContact], [fldEmpWorkPhone],
                   [fldEmpHomePhone],[fldEmpHomeCellPhone],[fldEmpAltPhone]) 
                   VALUES (@fldOnCallGroup, @fldStartOnCall, @fldEndOnCall, @fldRank, @fldEmpName, @fldOCPreferredContact, @fldEmpWorkPhone, @fldEmpHomePhone, 
                           @fldEmpHomeCellPhone, @fldEmpAltPhone)" 



    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblOnCallSchedule] SET [fldOnCallGroup] = @fldOnCallGroup, [fldStartOnCall] = @fldStartOnCall, 
                   [fldEndOnCall] = @fldEndOnCall, [fldRank] = @fldRank, [fldEmpName] = @fldEmpName, [fldOCPreferredContact] = @fldOCPreferredContact,
                   [fldEmpWorkPhone] = @fldEmpWorkPhone,[fldEmpHomePhone] = @fldEmpHomePhone,[fldEmpHomeCellPhone] = @fldEmpHomeCellPhone,
                   [fldEmpAltPhone] = @fldEmpAltPhone

                   WHERE [fldOCID] = @original_fldOCID">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboOncallGroup" Name="fldOnCallGroup" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldOCID" Type="Int16" />          
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldStartOnCall" DbType ="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEndOnCall" DbType ="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldStartOnCall" DbType="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEndOnCall" DbType="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="fldStartOnCall" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="fldEndOnCall" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />           
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldStartOnCall" DbType="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEndOnCall" DbType="Date" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
      </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Gridview Code:

```
<asp:Gridview ID="gvOnCallSchedule" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" showfooter="true"
        OnRowUpdating="GvOnCall_Update" onRowCommand="gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="fldOCID"
        BackColor="Aqua" DataSourceID="dsOncallGroup" Font-Bold="True"
        Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
        Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Justify" 
        CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboOnCallGroup_SelectedIndexChanged">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false"> 
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ImageURL="~/images/New.png" 
                         Text="Add" ToolTip="Add New On Call Record" />                
                </FooterTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Save.png" Text="Update" ToolTip="Update" />
                                &nbsp;
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel"
                                ImageURL="~/images/Cancel.png" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.gif" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />
                                &nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.png" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />   
            </asp:TemplateField>       

            <asp:Boundfield headertext="fldOCID" datafield="fldOCID" sortexpression="fldOCID" visible="false" InsertVisible="False" />               

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="On Call Group">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOCGroup" width="200px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOnCallGroup" Enabled="false"
                        DataSourceID= "dsListbox" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('fldOnCallGroup') %>"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ftrddlOCGroup" width="200px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOnCallGroup"
                        DataSourceID= "dsListbox" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('fldOnCallGroup') %>"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Start Date/Time">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtStartOnCall" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldStartOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="StartOnCallCal" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartOnCall" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtStartOnCallFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldStartOncall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopupFtr" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />    
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="StartOnCallCalFtr" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartOnCallFtr" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopupFtr" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>

                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="End Date/Time">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtEndOnCall" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEndOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="EndOnCallCal" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndOnCall" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup2" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtEndOnCallFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEndOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup2Ftr" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />    
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="EndOnCallCalFtr" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndOnCallFtr" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup2Ftr" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>

                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Call Order">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblCallOrder" runat="server" width="100" Text='<%# Bind("fldRank") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtCallOrderFtr" runat="server" width="100" Text='<%# Bind("fldOnCallGroup") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OnCall Analyst">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnalyst" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldEmpName"
                    datasourceID="dsEmp" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldEmpName") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnalystFtr" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldEmpName"
                        DataSourceID= "dsEmp" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldEmpName") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preferred Contact">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOCPreferredContact" Width="150px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOCPreferredContact"
                    datasourceID="dsPref" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldOCPreferredContact") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ftrddlOCPreferredContact" width="150px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOCPreferredContact"
                        DataSourceID= "dsPref" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldOCPreferredContact") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Work Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblWorkPhone" runat="server" width="90" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpWorkPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtWorkPhoneFtr" runat="server" width="90" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpWorkPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Home Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblHomePhone" runat="server" width="90" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomePhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtHomePhoneFtr" runat="server" width="90" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomePhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Personal Cell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblHomeCellPhone" runat="server" width="95" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomeCellPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtHomeCellPhoneFtr" runat="server" width="95" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomeCellPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Alternate Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblAltPhone" runat="server" width="105" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpAltPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtAltPhoneFtr" runat="server" width="105" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpAltPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    </asp:Gridview>
```

Comment: Could it be that you are manually binding the rowCommand event as well, causing it to execute twice?

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on the call to `dsOncallGroup.Insert()` and see if it is called twice, if so then it is your code doing it and you can figure out where the second call is happening by examining the `Call Stack` window (`Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack`).

If there are not two calls in the code, then you need to investigate if a trigger has been added to your database that is somehow causing extra data to be inserted.

Comment: I did the breakpoint and tried to debug but it doesnt tell me much.  Apologies, as I may not know what I'm looking for here.  All I know is that it was working a couple days ago, I havent changed the insert code on either the asp or the codebehind, and its now putting 2 identical rows for each insert.

Comment: I get 2 things in the Call stack.  I get a row that reads as follows:
    > App_Web_t1gwgbde.dll!_Default.gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand(Object sender = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView}, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs}) Line 168 Basic

Comment: Then I get a row that reads [External Code].  When I expand this out its too long to paste into this window.  First few lines...

      [Native to Managed Transition] 
  [Managed to Native Transition] 
  System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowCommand(System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e) + 0x6d bytes 
  System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(System.EventArgs e, bool causesValidation = true, string validationGroup) + 0x71 bytes 
  System.Web.dll!

Comment: Okay, I figured out that if I add the line "Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")" to reload the page after the insert call to my datasource, that it will only add 1 row to the database.  Problem is, I dont want to refresh the page to keep from inserting 2 rows.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: @user2956422 - when you put a break point on a line it is red, it will turn yellow when the break point is hit, then press F5 to continue running the program. Count how many times the break point turns yellow .

Comment: just once, I only see it once anyway.

Comment: Okay, it's red, it turns yellow as the breakpoint is hit, I hit F5 to continue, it is yellow again, I hit F5 again, it turns back to red and finishes processing. So it does appear that it's hitting that line of code twice. But how is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: @user2956422 - each time the break point is hit, look at the call stack window, it will show what the order (in reverse because it is a stack) of calls were, look at the first two lines and write them down. After doing this for both times the break point is hit, then report here what those call stack values are.

Comment: 1st time it hit: > App_Web_vvhu_wik.dll!_Default.gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand(Object sender = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView}, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs}) Line 168 Basic
------------------------------------------------------------------

2nd time it hit:
--------------------
> App_Web_vvhu_wik.dll!_Default.gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand(Object sender = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView}, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs e = {System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs}) Line 168 Basic

Comment: I also found the option that captures the breakpoint hit count.  It is hitting it twice.  This makes no sense because my code mirrors another project that works as it should.  Any Ideas?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2956422 - I noticed that the `Add` button does not contain a `CausesValidation="false"` value, but the other buttons do; any reason why? If you add that to the `Add` button does it still get called twice?

Comment: Still get the same result after adding "CausesValidation="false" to the "Add" button.  Hits breakpoint twice.

Comment: Any other suggestions?